# Iterating over Ruby hash while comparing values to another Ruby hash

Tags: ruby, hash

I have 2 Ruby objects that I am converting to hashes: one from XML and another from JSON.  When I `puts` the variable name I get hash, so it appears that I'm doing that correctly.

The format is several records in the format below.

Format of hash one (`smithjj` being a unique username):

```
{ smithjj => {office => 331, buidling => 1} }
```

Format of hash 2:

```
{"Data"=>{"xmlns:dmd"=>"http://www.xyz.com/schema/data-metadata",
"dmd:date"=>"2012-03-06", "Record"=>{"PCI"=>{"DPHONE3"=>nil, "OPHONE3"=>"111",
"DTY_DOB"=>"1956", "TEACHING_INTERESTS"=>nil, "FAX1"=>"123", "ROOMNUM"=>"111",
"DTD_DOB"=>"5", "DTM_DOB"=>"11", "WEBSITE"=>"www.test.edu", "FAX2"=>"324", 
"ENDPOS"=>"Director", "LNAME"=>"Smith", "FAX3"=>"4891", "MNAME"=>"Thomas",
"GENDER"=>"Male", "ALT_NAME"=>nil, "PFNAME"=>"TG", "id"=>"14101823488", 
"RESEARCH_INTERESTS"=>nil, "BIO"=>"", "CITIZEN"=>"Yes", "EMAIL"=>"test@email", 
"SUFFIX"=>nil, "DPHONE1"=>nil}, "termId"=>"234", "IndexEntry"=>{"text"=>"Other", 
"indexKey"=>"DEPARTMENT", "entryKey"=>"Other"}, "dmd:surveyId"=>"23424", 
"username"=>"smithers", "userId"=>"23324"}, "xmlns"=>"http://www.adsfda.com/"}}
```

I want to iterate over each unique username in the first hash and compare values from the PCI section of the second hash to the values in the first hash.  The keys are different names so I planned on pairing them up.

I've tried several ways of doing it, but I keep getting a string integer error, so I must not be iterating correctly.  I'm doing an `.each do` block, but all the examples I see show a simple hash, not a `key => key => value, key => value`.

Any direction is much appreciated.

Comment: Could you please format your code by indenting it four spaces? It'd be more likely to get a good answer then

Comment: will do thanks.. first time using this site.  Ill see if I can make it look better.

Comment: Also, how do you want to compare them?

Comment: Hash 1 has a key "office" I was to make sure its == to the PCI value of ROOMNUM in hash 2.  There are about 7 fields total I want to check.  I planned on setting a flag if one of the equality checks fail.  But I can't even get through the iteration part of the first hash ...

Comment: One more thing on formatting: You can add newlines to make it even _easier_ to read

Comment: added the new rows... my next post ill keep all these pointers in mind.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you should be able to do the iteration properly for hashes, if you're not already using this:

```
h = {:foo => 42, :bar => 43, 44 => :baz}
h.each {|key, val| puts "The value at #{key} is #{val}."}
```

This produces:

```
The value at foo is 42.
The value at bar is 43.
The value at 44 is baz.
```

As for the last part of your question, could you please make it a little clearer? e.g., what error are you getting exactly? This could help us understand the issue more.

EDIT: If what you'd like to do is compare certain values against others, try something like this:

```
h1 = {:foo => 42, :bar => 43, 44 => :baz, :not_used => nil}
h2 = {:life_universe => 42, :fourty_three => 45, :another_num => 44, :unused => :pancakes}
# Very easy to add more
comparisons = {:foo => :life_universe, :bar => :fourty_three, :baz => :another_num}
def all_match_up?(hash1, hash2, comps)
  comparisons.each {|key, val|
    if key != val
      # They don't match!
      puts "#{key} doesnt match #{val}!"
      return false
    end
  }
  # They all match!
  true
end
all_match_up?(h1, h2, comparisons)
```

Try this to see what happens ;)

Comment: Does you example apply to this format of a hash.  Looks like you have all key => values.  Mine is {key => {key => value, key => value}}.  I can get it to iterate over just plain values, Im having an issue iterating over the first key, then printing out all the key values for the first key.  Make sense?

Comment: So wait, if you have a hash like {:foo => {:bar => 43, :baz => :44}} do you want it to iterate over _every single_ key in every hash inside the top level hash, or _only_ over the hash at say, :foo?